# Blueprint CSS framework (compress.rb) will not "compile" some changes

Tags: css, blueprint-css

I use Sass to compose my CSS, and Blueprint as my framework. Since I'm using these tools for a Django application, my workflow is:

1. Edit scss file in emacs while `sass --watch` is running
2. Save the file and alt-tab to terminal to run `ruby compress.rb -p project1`
3. Reset my local dev server
4. View changes in the page

However recently I added some changes, and Blueprint will not include them in the compilation from typography/forms/grid/reset.css files to screen/print/ie.css. The scss files passed validation from Sass, and the changes are in the Sass-compiled CSS files. They are not, however, in the final screen.css file. How do I fix this? It's very frustrating.

Comment: Not sure I understand - are you combining your css with the blueprint css?

Comment: Is it possible the changes conflict and you need to add !important in your added changes?

Comment: Do the old rules still appear in the compiled CSS, or do the rules not appear at all? Can you give an example of rules that aren't getting updated?

Comment: Is it possible you're linking to the wrong generated css file? I had this problem once where for some reason, the compile-to location changed, so I had one out-of-date css file being linked to, and the updated one not being used.

Answer (score 1):

`sass --watch` watches for changes. If the file it's watching hasn't changed, then it won't recompile it.

This bit me in the ass on one project where I made extensive changes to various partials, which never showed up in the generated CSS file, since, of course I hadn't actually edited the file sass was watching.